# Sending data to JFrame from another sub JFrame without opening a new JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am doing a project of bus reservation system in java swing. There I have a problem with passing data from one to another.

See i have a frame where i have the seats to be booked. And by clicking **select** button the data will be stored in a text field and it will send to the main frame as selected seat.

[image]

The main frame is

[image]

But i have a problem with that whenever I'm clicking on **select** button the old frame isn’t opening. It opens a new frame. How i could solve this. From opening the new frame.

The code of frame seat Selection is

```
private void selectbuttonActionPerformed{
    String seats = seatstf.gettext();
    new Billing(seats).setVisible(true);
    this.dispose();
}
```

And the main frame Billing code is

```
public Billing(String seats){
    initComponents();
    This.seatvar = seats;
    Seattf.setText(""+seatvar);
}
```

Where `new Billing(seats).setVisible(true);` is opening a new Billing frame without opening the old one where the data is needed in text field.

How could it be solved?

Comment: *"Sending data to JFrame from another sub JFrame"* The *"sub JFrame"* should likely be a (modal) `JDialog`. See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `new Billing` you create an instance of the frame which of course opens a new frame.
Save the frame as an instance variable and use it.

```
public class SeatFrame extends JFrame {
    private Billing parent;

    public SeatFrame(Billing parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
        // TODO init Frame (add Components etc.)
    }

    ...

    private void selectbuttonActionPerformed(){
        String seats = seatstf.gettext();
        parent.setSeats(seats);
        parent.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    }

    ...

}
```

The Billing-class should look like this:

```
...

public Billing(){
    initComponents();
}

public void setSeats(String seats){
    this.seatvar = seats;
    Seattf.setText(seatvar);
}

public void openSeatFrame(){
   new SeatFrame(this).setVisible(true);
   this.dispose();
}

....
```

Comment: No. it’s not working. A new frame is opening with the selected seats frame.

Comment: @hasanrafi Sorry, my mistake. When the frame for seat selection is created, a new instance of billing is automatically created. I have adapted my code, it should work now.

Comment: i tried with the new code you have provide in the comment. I have got a problem in the seat selection frame and it is mentioned as "selectbuttonActionPerforemd(evt)" error.

Comment: @hasanrafi how do you set your ActionListener? try this implementation `selectButton.addActionListener(e -> selectbuttonActionPerformed());`